# Building custom dynamic and static file delivery on nodejs

Tags: node.js, http

I am building my own system to deliver static  and dynamic files on node js using http server.
I know that this middleware is not sophisticated.  So what I am looking for is to achieve my own way to deliver static and dynamic file  on nodejs .
In the code below I created a `http server`.  The server reads two types of files according to `counter` variable

```
   1- Dynamic file (myhtml.html) when  counter =  1 
   2- Static files(images, scripts etc.. )  when counter > 1 . Located on directory /public
```

It works well but a problem arise when  I refresh again the web page after a `first request`,  because the `counter` value has been already  incremented each time a file( static or dynamic ) is delivered . So for  subsequent request initial value of `counter`  is no longer  0 ,  thus deliver   `error 404` with  message `file not  found` .

**NB : If I refresh the server then everything work well because counter is 0 .**

*So my question is how to make  `counter to equal to 0` when all files has been delivered after one http request so that for the next requests `counter starts from  0 instead` .*

```
var http = require("http");
var root = __dirname;
var mime = require("mime");
var path = require("path") ;
var fs   = require("fs");
function deliverDynamicFile(file, res, req, type){
   readAndSendFile(file, req, res, type)
}

function deliverStaticFile(res, req, type){
   let static = path.join(root,"public");  // ex : static =  root/public/
   let file = path.join(static,req.url);  // ex  : file = root/public/images/java.jpeg

   readAndSendFile(file, req, res, type)
}

function readAndSendFile(file, req, res, type){
   fs.readFile(file,(err,data)=>{
     if(err) {
        res.writeHead(404,{"content-type":"text/plain"});
        res.end("file not found") 
     }
     else  {
       
        res.writeHead(200,{"content-type":type});
        res.end(data) 
     }
   })
}

let counter = 0 ;
var server = http.createServer( function(req,res){
   let url = req.url ;
   counter++;  // increment counter for each request
   let file = path.join(root,url) ;
   let mimeType = mime.lookup(path.basename(file));

   if (counter == 1 ){
      deliverDynamicFile(file,res, req, mimeType)
   }else{
      // deliver files on directory `public`
      deliverStaticFile(res, req, mimeType)
   }
 });

  
server.listen(3000);
```

My html file  :`myhtml.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> RAW REQUEST</title>
    <script src="/handlebars/handlebars-v4.5.3.js"></script>
 </head>
   <body>
     <h1>Hello raw REQUEST</h1>
     <img src="/images/java.jpeg" width="200px" height="200px">
   </body>
 </html>
```

My application directory

```
server.js
myhtml.html
public/
- - images/
- - - - -java.jpeg
- - handlebars/
- - - - -handlebars-v4.5.3.js
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check for one using the `modulo` operator like this:

```
var http = require("http");
var root = __dirname;
var mime = require("mime");
var path = require("path") ;
var fs   = require("fs");
function deliverDynamicFile(file, res, req, type){
   readAndSendFile(file, req, res, type)
}

function deliverStaticFile(res, req, type){
   let static = path.join(root,"public");  // ex : static =  root/public/
   let file = path.join(static,req.url);  // ex  : file = root/public/images/java.jpeg

   readAndSendFile(file, req, res, type)
}

function readAndSendFile(file, req, res, type){
   fs.readFile(file,(err,data)=>{
     if(err) {
        res.writeHead(404,{"content-type":"text/plain"});
        res.end("file not found") 
     }
     else  {
       
        res.writeHead(200,{"content-type":type});
        res.end(data) 
     }
   })
}

let counter = 0 ;
var server = http.createServer( function(req,res){
   let url = req.url ;
   counter++;  // increment counter for each request
   let file = path.join(root,url) ;
   let mimeType = mime.lookup(path.basename(file));

   if (counter % 2 == 1 ){
      deliverDynamicFile(file,res, req, mimeType)
   }else{
      // deliver files on directory `public`
      deliverStaticFile(res, req, mimeType)
   }
 });

  
server.listen(3000);
```

This way for each request you check the result of the counter modulo 2. If the result is 1 you do what you want.

See also this: https://www.tutorialsmade.com/javascript-find-odd-even-number/

Comment: it not working   since 3%2 = 1 like  1%2 = 1  @Manos Kounelakis